# Bring, to foreground, a specific program 'path\app.exe' if it is running using api in vb6

Tags: winapi, vb6

I am trying to use api functions inside vb6 that will allow me to bring a program to the foreground if it is running.  At which point I will use sendkeys to send key strokes to the program in question.

The kicker is that the only thing I know about the program is its path and .exe name. For instance, 'c:\anyfolder\anyprog.exe'.

I can find all kinds of info on how to do this if I know other things about the program but not if I only know the above (not even what the title bar says when it is in the foreground, which the program itself changes regularly).

Is there a way to do this?

So far, with Remy's help, I have this vb6 code where I try to convert C code from [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701.aspx) to vb6.  But it is not quite working, any ideas?

```
Private Sub FillLists_Click()
   PathList.Clear
   FileNameList.Clear
   Dim p As Long
   Dim m As Long
   Dim ml As Long
   Dim hProcessSnapshot As Long
   Dim h As Long
   Dim hl As Long
   Dim uProcess As PROCESSENTRY32
   Dim uModule As MODULEENTRY32

   hProcessSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0&)
   If hProcessSnapshot = 0 Then Exit Sub

   uProcess.dwSize = Len(uProcess)
   p = ProcessFirst(hProcessSnapshot, uProcess)
   Do While p 'as long as p is not 0
      h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, uProcess.th32ProcessID)
      hl = GetLastError()

      uModule.dwSize = Len(uModule)
      m = Module32First(h, uModule)
      ml = GetLastError()

      PathList.AddItem "h=" & h & " hl=" & hl & " m=" & m & " ml=" & ml & uModule.szModule

      FileNameList.AddItem uProcess.szExeFile

      Call CloseHandle(h)
      p = ProcessNext(hProcessSnapshot, uProcess)
   Loop
   Call CloseHandle(hProcessSnapshot)
End Sub
```

AND the output from that:

[image]

So, the above did not work, likely because vb6 is 32bit and my computer is Win7 64 bit.  I found this function on a Google search for 'vb6 QueryFullProcessImageName' from a Russian forum thread, couldn't read the comments but the code was golden!

```
Function GetProcessNameByPID(pid As Long) As String
    Const PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION As Long = &H1000
    Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION         As Long = &H400
    Const MAX_PATH                          As Long = 260
    Dim hProc               As Long
    Dim Path                As String
    Dim lStr                As Long
    Dim inf(68)             As Long
    Dim IsVistaAndLater     As Boolean
    inf(0) = 276: GetVersionEx inf(0): IsVistaAndLater = inf(1) >= 6
    If Not IsVistaAndLater Then Exit Function
    hProc = OpenProcess(IIf(IsVistaAndLater, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION), False, pid)
    If hProc <> 0 Then 'INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
        lStr = MAX_PATH
        Path = Space(lStr)
        ' minimum Windows Vista !!!!!!!
        If QueryFullProcessImageName(hProc, 0, StrPtr(Path), lStr) Then
            GetProcessNameByPID = Left$(Path, lStr)
        End If
        CloseHandle hProc
    End If
End Function
```

Now my code is:

```
Private Sub FillLists_Click()
   PathList.Clear
   FileNameList.Clear
   Dim p As Long
   Dim hProcessSnapshot As Long
   Dim uProcess As PROCESSENTRY32

   hProcessSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0&)
   If hProcessSnapshot = 0 Then Exit Sub

   uProcess.dwSize = Len(uProcess)
   p = ProcessFirst(hProcessSnapshot, uProcess)
   Do While p 'as long as p is not 0

      PathList.AddItem GetProcessNameByPID(uProcess.th32ProcessID)

      FileNameList.AddItem uProcess.szExeFile

      p = ProcessNext(hProcessSnapshot, uProcess)
   Loop
   Call CloseHandle(hProcessSnapshot)
End Sub
```

AND the output from that is (and the rest is just do a AppActivate uProcess.th32ProcessID when you find the one you want):

[image]

THANKS REMY!

EDIT:   Be careful, it turns out that you can't bring another application to the foreground if the application that is causing another app to come to foreground in minimized.  I also needed to enumerate only the apps in the Alt-Tab group of programs and use api's in a way that forced a window to the foreground, not AppActivate or the SetForeGroundWindow() by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to:

1. enumerate all running processes, looking at their full paths and filenames until you find the one you are interested in. Use [`EnumProcesses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629.aspx) or [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx) for that. See [Enumerating All Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623.aspx) and [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701.aspx) for examples.  Once you find the desired filename, you will know its Process ID.
2. use [`EnumWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) and [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to enumerate all top-level windows looking for the one(s) that belong to the same Process ID.  Then you can restore those window(s) as needed (if you have permission to do so, that is - see all of the restrictions mentioned in the documentation for [`SetForegroundWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx)).  If a window is minimized, you can try sending it a [`WM_SYCOMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360.aspx)/`SC_RESTORE` message.  But if the window is already non-minimized but just not focused, you might run into resistence trying to focus it programmably.

Comment: In 1. - So far I am only able to see how to enumerate the output of CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to match the executable name from the type PROCESSENTRY32.  How do I confirm the path too?  Don't forget I am trying to do this in vb6.

Comment: If you read the [`PROCESSENTRY32` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx), it says: "*szExeFile - The name of the executable file for the process. **To retrieve the full path to the executable file, call the `Module32First` function and check the `szExePath` member of the `MODULEENTRY32` structure that is returned. However, if the calling process is a 32-bit process, you must call the `QueryFullProcessImageName` function to retrieve the full path of the executable file for a 64-bit process**.*"

Comment: I am having a hard time with running Module32First, are you able to comment on my vb6 test code in the question? Thanks.

Comment: You are not checking the result of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` for errors correctly. In the first call, you are checking for `= 0`.  In the second call, you are checking for `<= 0` instead.  On failure, it returns -1 only, so check for only that value, anything else is valid. Also, you should log the process ID and error code when `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` fails, you might see a pattern (like querying system processes that you don't have permissions to access). Another way to enumerate a process's modules is to use `OpenProcess()` and `EnumProcessModules()` instead of `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`.

Comment: I am trying to add the correct error constant to check for but I don't know how to put this in my definition module from the api: Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Long = ((Handle) - 1)  ---- Handle generates a variable not defined error.  I just assumed 0 and -1 were invalid.  Without any lineerror code in there, I never got any paths.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed that lousy attempt at debugging.

Comment: 14 of those h=-1 programs are ones that I have started and for sure I should have permission to access them.  Also I am logged in as administrator.

Comment: Since you defined `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` as a `Long`, simply set its value to `-1` instead of `(Handle)-1`.  Also, you are still not logging the process ID or the error code from `GetLastError()` when `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` fails. That is useful diagnostic information. Also, are you running on a 32bit or 64bit version of Windows? Your vb6 app is 32bit, so calling `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE)` with a process ID of a 64bit process will fail with a `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` (299) error code.

Comment: That was it, I am running vb6 on 64 bit Win7 machine, but I only get 299 on some files.  Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: Is that why I always get error 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER on the GetLastError for the Module32First?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98755/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-kiloone).